# Java inventory project

Tags: java, project, editing, inventory

The question is: 
Project 5. Classes Inventory, ProductItem, ProductShoe, ProductPants, ProductShirt. Class Inventory is a collection of ProductItem instances. Class ProductItem is a base class, with private member unique integer product id and string product item description. Classes ProductShoe, ProductPants and ProductShirt inherit from ProductItem, each of these classes shall have private members reflecting at least three properties (quantity is one of them) for each product and corresponding setter and getter functions. Main application interacts with the user using keystrokes (console application) allowing him/her to list product items, create/show/edit product items.
Code is as following:

```
    public class ProductItem {

    private int productid;
    private int productquantity;
    private String productdesc;


    //constructor : sets product id,quantity and description to 0 if no parameters given
    public ProductItem()
    {
        productid=0;
        productquantity=0;
        productdesc="No description given";
    }

    //overload constructor : sets product id,quantity and description to whatever parameters given
    public ProductItem(int id, int quantity, String desc)
    {
        productid=id;
        productquantity=quantity;
        productdesc=desc;
    }

    //sets a new id for productid
    public void setid (int newid)
    {productid=newid;}

    //sets a new id for productquantity
    public void setquantity (int newquantity)
    {productquantity=newquantity;}

    //sets a new id for productdesc
    public void setdesc (String newdesc)
    {productdesc=newdesc;}

    //get function that returns productid
    public int getid()
    {return productid;}

    //get function that returns productquantity
    public int getquantity()
    {return productquantity;}

    //get function that returns productdesc
    public String getdesc()
    {return productdesc;}

    //method to output ProductId
    public void outputid()
    {System.out.println("Product Id: " + productid);}

    //method to output ProductQuantity
    public void outputquantity()
    {System.out.println("Product Quantity: " + productquantity);}

    //method to output ProductDesc
    public void outputdesc()
    {System.out.println("Product Description: " + productdesc);}

    }

__________________________________________________________________

import java.util.Scanner;
//
public class Inventory extends ProductItem {

    //Show item
        public void printitem()
        {
            super.outputid();
            super.outputquantity();
            super.outputdesc();
        }

    //create item
        public ProductItem itemcreation()
        {
            ProductItem newitem = new ProductItem();
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            int newid;
            System.out.println("Enter new value for ID: ");
            super.setid(newid= keyboard.nextInt());
            int newquantity;
            System.out.println("Enter new value for Quantity: ");
            super.setquantity(newquantity= keyboard.nextInt());
            String newdesc;
            System.out.println("Enter new value for Description: ");
            super.setdesc(newdesc= keyboard.nextLine());
            return newitem;
        }

    //edit item
        public void itemediting ()
        {

        }
```

---

I can not for the life of me fathom how i can have the user edit specific Objects of ProductItem such as ProductShit//ProductShoes//ProductPants or even harder their own created item.  Any feed back will be greatly appreciated, this is 25% of my grade -_-

Comment: Look up the concept of **inheritance** mentioned in your question. You will need individual classes for each of the products. Ask the user for the type of product first, then create the proper one based on the input.

Comment: Your methods should be [camelCase](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/08/java-naming-conventions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of a solution

```
start application
get user input
if user wants to create, create item and add the item to inventory
else if user wants to see all items, show all items
else if user wants to edit item, edit item
else if user wants to exist, exit application
```

For actual code, I suggest using an ArrayList of ProductItems, ie `ArrayList<ProductItem> inventory=...`, and having the user pass in parameters. Like if the user typed `create shirt param1 param2 param3` then a shirt would be created with the given parameters and added to inventory, ie `inventory.add(new ProductShirt(param1,param2,param3));`

Check out the [String.split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method for more infomation on how to accomplish this